# Import of already defined const won't throw error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, ecmascript-6, firefox-addon-webextensions, es6-modules

I have a html file that loads two scripts: `utils.js` and `background.js`.

In the `utils.js` I have defined:

```
const test = 'a';
```

In the `background.js` I have:

```
import {test} from "./modules/hosts.js";  // no error here
console.log(test);                        // 'b' is printed
```

Module `hosts.js` defines:

```
const test = 'b';
```

I would expect the import to fail because `test` is already defined, but it works and the `test` is overloaded with value from the `host.js` module.
**Why it works?**

**EDIT:**
HTML file:

```
    <script type="application/javascript" src="utils/utils.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="background.js"></script>
```

Comment: @wOxxOm sorry for missing info... I will try to build MCVE next time. I've added snippet of html where you can see that `utils.js` is not loaded as module. Also when I comment out the `import` line, it will print "a" as expected.

Comment: Ah, background.js is loaded as a module so its lexical environment is different from the global one where utils.js resides. Each module has its own namespace, which is one of the good things about modules.

Comment: @wOxxOm I see now, I can even create same `const` in the `background.js` and it won't fail. That's a very good thing to know about! Thank you!